# Bani Israil in west Africa, Jews of bilad al sudan

Tags: bani-israel

I have been informed of a large body of Bani Israil (children of Israel) in west Africa that were well recorded by Muslim historians and chroniclers. According to the Tarikh al sudan and the Tarikh al fatash there was a great many Bani Israil in west Africa and many other historians also state the many Bani Israil migrated south into Africa after the Roman judaen war of 70 ad and that many Judaen communities who lived in Egypt and Libya migrated deeper into the interior of Africa.

Many Muslim scholars have told me that the European Ashkenazi jews living in Israel today are not descendants of the Bani Israil but that the European Jews are descendants of Khazar converts whom converted to Talmudic Judaism around the 800 ad.

Also an Israeli geneticist Dr. Eran Elhaik has confirmed the "khazar theory" with over  an 11year DNA research of the Ashkenazi Jewish DNA and origins and his findings confirm their Khazar origins. The "khazar theory" has also been confirmed by another Israeli scientist Dr Ariella Oppenheim.

I have been told by Muslim scholars that the so called Negroes in America are descendants of the jews of Bilad al Sudan and were taken as slaves out of Africa and therefore the Negroes are Bani Israil but became disconnected from their heritage through slavery.

Interestingly majority of the so called African Americans are for the most part from the IBO (Igbo) people and the IBO people of west Africa have been traced to the Israelite tribes of Gad, Zebulon, Manasseh Ephraim and Judah. There are many Rabbi's and the state of Israel showing interest in them and studying them. There is a documentary on the subject. Several editions of the Encyclopaedia Britannica in 1929 connect the Igbo people to Gad. A Torah commentary on Sh’mot in 1922 made the Igbo-Gad connection also.

This has also been put forward by Christians as well.

Anglican Missionary G.T. Basden, the first to minister to the Igbo wrote many books which claimed and connected the Igbos to the tribes of Israel.

Are the Negroes that were taken out of west Africa into slavery descendants of the jews of bilad al Sudan and are bani Israil?

Do any Islamic scholars have answers about this?

Comment: @user5751924. I have edited my question to bettet adress the matter. Please view my question now with the updates and perhaps the edit may alter your answer. I am asking sincerely and looking for open minded non-bias answers, thank you and may Allah most gracious most merciful bless you.

Comment: I don't see how this has *anything* to do with the topic of Islam.

Answer (score 2):

> Many Muslim scholars have told me that the European Ashkenazi jews living in Israel today are not descendants of the Bani Israil but that the European Jews are descendants of Khazar converts whom converted to Talmudic Judaism around the 800 ad.

This looks like a huge approximation of history.

The jewish world population was [already scattered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_diaspora#Pre-Roman_diaspora) around the mediterranean sea before the judeo-roman wars, due to the invasion from various empires (Assyrian, Babylonian, ...). A large part of the population still lived in Israel. These wars scattered the jewish community even more, some away from the empire, where they endured discriminations.

The hypothesis that most [azkhenazi jews descend from a Turkish tribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khazar_hypothesis_of_Ashkenazi_ancestry) from central Asia is mostly regarded as false, especially since the apparition of genetics studies which counter it. But even if it were true, it wouldn't change the existence of important [jewish communities around the Rhine](http://www.museenkoeln.de/archaeologische-zone/default.asp?s=4303#top) in the late roman empire, before the Khazar conversions.

As for [contemporary scholars involved in this theory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmgWNDF8ttg), it looks mostly like an anti-zionist political move. The description of the "Khazar" which this scholar gives reminds me of your average illuminati-related ramblings.

> Are the Negroes that were taken out of west Africa into slavery descendants of the jews of bilad al Sudan and are bani Israil?

Unlike ancient east african jewish communities, the emigration of jewish populations in west africa was mostly due to fleeing either muslim or christian rule, with a significant escape away Spain (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Africa)). Some even went further south when they were asked to convert or leave in the Songhai empire.

During the 3 centuries in which it took place, around [15.3 million persons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_slave_trade#Atlantic_shipment) taken out of west Africa by the Atlantic slave trade arrived in the American continents. Many others died on the trip. It is *litterally impossible* that a significant part of them were jewish, considering the jewish population at that time.

Since most of these slaves were bought to the local african authorities, it is possible that some preferred to sell the jewish minorities. But it would still be a negligible amount, and quite hard to verify.

> Do any Islamic scholars have answers about this?

I read [here](http://www.learnnc.org/lp/editions/nchist-colonial/1972) that most of the african records on which historians base themselves are from Islamic scholars.